# MySQL Database is not saving the data I insert but 0's

Tags: php, mysql, database, forms, types

I have a booking form and I successfully connected my database to my website. When I go to my database in MYSQL to see the data I inserted, all fields are in zeros. I tried changing my type of my data fields in the database but it didn't work.

My website connection with the MYSQL database:

```
<?php 
$conexao=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sitepap2");

?>
```

Code to sends the data inserted in the form to the database and to check if there's already a similar record in the database:

```
    <?php

    include("conecta.php");

    $pnome=$_POST['pnome'];
    $numerotmv=$_POST['numerotmv'];
    $localsessao=$_POST['localsessao'];
    $data=$_POST['data'];
    $hora=$_POST['hora'];

    $pesquisaUsuario = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($conexao,"
        SELECT nome FROM agendamento
        WHERE numerotmv = '$numerotmv'  
    "));


    if($pesquisaUsuario >0){
        echo 1;
    }else{
        mysqli_query($conexao, "
        insert into agendamento 
        (pnome, numerotmv, localsessao, data, hora)           
        values
        ('$pnome','$numerotmv', '$localsessao','$data','$hora')
        ");     
        echo 0;
    }



?>
```

My index file where the form is displayed:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="calendario" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Registro --> 
        <form name="calendario" id="calendario" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="text-uppercase align-self-end text-center">Agendamento</h2>
            <hr class="divider">
        </div>      

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Primeiro Nome</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pnome" required="required">
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Número de telemóvel</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numerotmv" required="required">
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Local da Sessão</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localsessao" required="required">
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="data" type="date" required>
                    <span class="form-label">Data</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="hora" type="time" required>
                    <span class="form-label">Hora</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
                    <button type="submit" onClick="verificarAgendamento()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Agendar</button>
                </div>  
            </div>            
    </form>
            </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    <script>
        function verificarAgendamento(){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "agendamento.php",
            data: $("#calendario").serialize(),
            success: function(resultado){

                if(resultado==0){

                        alert("Booking made with success");

                   }else{
                       alert("error");

                   }
                return false;
            }

        });
            $('#calendario')[0].reset();
            return false;

        }   
        </script>



</body>
</html>
```

My database structure:
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8dS4.png)

What happens when I try to insert data through my PHP form in the database:
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xIcw.png)

Thank to all the people that spent time reading this post to help me. I'm grateful.

Comment: What if user B inserts while user A is 'checking'?

Comment: Also, see about sql injection, and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two id's called calendario. The form and the div. So your ajax request is serializing the div, not the form.

Change one of the ids to a unique value and it will work e.g.:

NOTE: If you change the id of your form you need to change it in your ajax call as well

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>PHP form</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="modal fade" id="calendario" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Registro --> 
        <form name="calendario" id="calendario-form" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
        <div>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="text-uppercase align-self-end text-center">Agendamento</h2>
            <hr class="divider">
        </div>      

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Primeiro Nome</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pnome" required="required">
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Número de telemóvel</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="numerotmv" required="required">
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label col-xs-4">Local da Sessão</label>
            <div class="col-xs-8">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="localsessao" required="required">
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="data" type="date" required>
                    <span class="form-label">Data</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" name="hora" type="time" required>
                    <span class="form-label">Hora</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-4">
                    <button type="submit" onClick="verificarAgendamento()" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Agendar</button>
                </div>  
            </div>            
    </form>
            </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

    <script>
        function verificarAgendamento(){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "agendamento.php",
            data: $("#calendario-form").serialize(),
            success: function(resultado){

                if(resultado==0){

                        alert("Booking made with success");

                   }else{
                       alert("error");

                   }
                return false;
            }

        });
            $('#calendario')[0].reset();
            return false;

        }   
        </script>



</body>
</html>
```